# Action in rendered sub template not bubbled to route since upgrade to Ember2.4

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just updated my app from the latest Ember 1.13 (without any deprecations) to Ember 2.4. Now I have the problem that some actions are not bubbling anymore. I have the following setting:

routes/foo.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions:
        doSomething: function() {
            console.log("action triggered!");
        }
});
```

templates/foo.hbs

```
{{render "foo.bar"}}
```

templates/foo/bar.hbs

```
<div {{action "doSomething"}}>Test</div>
```

controllers/foo/bar.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
});
```

With Ember 1.13, when I clicked `Test`, the action `doSomething` in `routes/foo.js` was triggered. Now this does not happen anymore. If I add an action `doSomething` to `controllers/foo/bar.js`, this action is triggered, but nevertheless it does not bubble to the base root. I checked all the blog posts on new ember versions but I could find nothing that suggested the bubbling of actions was changed and how to fix it. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the **[render documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_render)**, render helper only has access to its own controller and not the parent. But you can use the `render` method in the route to render to a named outlet and have the behavior you desire.

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render();
    this.render('bar', {
      into: 'foo',
      outlet: 'bar',
    });
  },
  actions: {
    doSomething: function() {
      alert('Done');
    }
  }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
  {{outlet 'bar'}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bar">
  <button {{action 'doSomething'}}>Do Something</button>
</script>
```

**[Here is a working example.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ripufo/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: Thankyou a lot! Actually, I can't use outlet, because I pass some data to the sub controller via `{{render "foo.bar" model.something}}`. I guess I have to use a component then, but from the documentation I cannot infer that the behaviour changed since Ember 1.13. Did I miss something?

Comment: You may want to do a search on ember github issues with 'render'. I do remember render helper had many unintended bahviour and Ember 2 may have corrected those. You can pass the model into the render method. There are other options which you can use http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render

Comment: Ah, that is interesting, I was not aware of this. However, I use `{{render}}` inside a loop, where I am passing different things to `{{render}}`. From the documentation I guess that was never a intended use for render ("Note: A given controller may only be used once in your app in this manner"), thus I will change to a component now. Thankyou for your help!